# Python 7BOOM problem, why is it not working?

Tags: python, statements

I got a question that I need to print all the numbers from 40 to 80 that don't have the digit 7 in them, and that is not divisible with 7.

Well I've wanted to loop through the numbers, and then check if the number are not divisible by 7 or don't have the digit 7 in them then I will print the number.

This is what I've written:

```
for i in range(40,81):
if i % 7 != 0 or i % 10 != 7 or i // 10  != 7:
    print(i)
```

What is printed when I do this is just all the numbers from 40 to 80, except 77.

Any help why?

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `i` as long as *one* of its digits is not 7; you need to ensure that *neither* digit is 7, by using `and` instead of `or`.

```
if i % 7 != 0 or (i % 10 != 7 and i // 10  != 7):
```

Comment: Yeah I got that after sitting and running the thing through my head..